# Importando Modulo Dentro Do Modulo Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Há as seguintes pastas:

```
└── Programa/
    ├── main.py             <----- Inicio esse...
    ├── bin/
    |   └── config.py           <----- esse importa o db.py
    └── database/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── db.py
```

No console apresenta que não existe o módulo `db`, sendo que eu inicio o `main`, que importa o `config` e o `config` importa o `db`.

Mas quando eu importo o `db` direto do `main` não dá erro.

Comment: Poderia [edit] e adicionar à pergunta os códigos relevantes à importação em cada arquivo?

Answer (score 0):

Se você apenas der um import db, ele vai varrer as pastas e subpastas de onde está sendo executado.
Importando dessa forma no config.py, ele irá procurar o arquivo importado (db.py) dentro da pasta em que está (bin/) e subpastas (no caso não existe nenhuma, dentro da bin/ contém apenas o config.py).
Importando direto do main.py, ele irá varrer tanto os arquivos de sua pasta (que contém o main.py), quanto suas subpastas (que são a bin/ e a database/), e aí sim ele irá encontrar o db.py, que está dentro de database/

Caso queira importar o db.py dentro do config.py, na hora do import coloque o caminho todo em que ele se encontra, começando na raíz ('/').